# PCB design software alternative to Upverter?

Tags: windows, osx, cad

I use [Upverter](https://upverter.com/) for my printed circuit board (PCB) designs, but I'm looking for an alternative:

- I need autorouting (Upverter does not have that)
- Should be able to collaborate with others
- Support both Mac and Windows.
- Something affordable, currently Upverters pricing is $100 a month per engineer, this is far beyond anything I can afford. I can pay up to £45 - 50 a month, but not per engineer.

Comment: Collaboration is a tall order. However, have you considered a EDA tool + a VCS (svn or git)? [Kicad](http://kicad-pcb.org/) is an open-source professional EDA tool that is under active development and sufficient for most designs. (And, I will add, far more capable than Fritzing.)

Comment: @Alex [Electronics.se] may also be a source for you, I see questions like [this](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/4475/which-pcb-software-has-the-best-autorouter).

Comment: I will take a note of the formatting for this question and make sure all my questions are clear and answerable.

Answer (score 1):

Fritzing is an open-source initiative to support designers, artists, researchers and hobbyists to take the step from physical prototyping to actual product. We are creating this software in the spirit of Processing and Arduino, developing a tool that allows users to document their Arduino and other electronic-based prototypes, share them with others, teach electronics in a classroom, and to create a pcb layout for manufacturing.
[Link for the software's official website](http://fritzing.org/)

Comment: I have used Fritzing before, but it has no collaboration feature.